# Comments does not work?

Tags: comments

I have a big problem: The comments on my theme does not work. I see only the following PHP errors:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/hosts/dev.example.com/www/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 209 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/hosts/dev.example.com/www/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 209 Anonymous schreibt:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/hosts/dev.example.com/www/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 600
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/hosts/dev.example.com/www/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 375 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/hosts/dev.example.com/www/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 631 Uhr
```

what can i do?

Answer (score 2):

From quick look at code these seem all to be about trying to do something with comment object, returned by [`get_comment()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment) function. However from this little information it is impossible to tell what goes wrong with it. Could be something about retrieveing comment from database, could be trying to retrieve comment by wrong ID, etc.

Have you tried switching theme (preferably to native Twenty Eleven) and checking if comments work there?

Comment: Hi Rarst! When i try it with TwentyTen Eleven, it works and with my theme it works not.

Comment: @hazelnut then the issue is with your theme. Add theme's name to the question if it's publicly available. I am not sure from your wording is it your theme like you developed it or third party theme you are using.

Comment: Its i theme that i have developed. What infos do you need about it?

Comment: @hazelnut source of `comments.php` (or however you have your related code organized)? When and how exactly you get those error messages?

Comment: I got this Error message under an Blogpost at the Comments Sections. Here is the Code: http://pastebin.com/wjsgdKRh

Comment: @hazelnut that looks overly manual way to do it. I'd look into `wp_list_comments()`, `comment_form()` and such. Just look how Twenty Eleven does that and try to work from there.